# Подсветка синтаксиса в nano (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, консоль

Добрый вечер! Я пишу на C/C++ и мне иногда очень не хочется заходить в какую-либо IDE для написания кода (особенно, когда решаю заадчки). 
Я знаю, что в nano можно подключить подсветку синтаксиса многих ЯП, в файле /etc/nanorc в конце есть упомнияния обо всех языках, только вот беда в том, что в разных манах сказано о том, что бы строки типа такой:

```
#include "/usr/share/nano/pov.nanorc"
```

Должны быть разкомментированны. Только вот беда в том, что они уже у меня все расскоментированы, а подсветки все равно никакой нет!

Прошу помочь и рассказать, как и что сделать!

Comment: раскомментировал строку

    include "/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc"

и все заработало (в данном случае для с и с++).

Проверьте наличие файла.

Да, кстати, вим значительно легче в освоении.

Comment: файл существет, в нудном месте! я туда зашел с того же nano, но проблема в том, чт овсе те строки у меня УЖЕ расскоментированы! А подсветки синтаксиса нет!
А за совет на счет vim спасибо, я подумаю. А то просто как-то видел его - с первого взгляда для меня он оказалс очень страшным: я без гугла даже не понял бы как от туда выйти и сохранить файл! :D

Answer (score 1):

По синтаксису почитайте `man nano` и `man nanorc`. В последнем много интересного по Вашему вопросу.
При открытии файла на редактирование попробуйте явно задавать `--syntax=[PL]`

Answer (score 1):

Я ни разу не пользовался этим nano но могу предположить что в файле настроек где подключается подсветка синтаксиса строчкой

```
#include "/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc"
```

для комментария используется символ '#'.

А вы как C\C++ программист думаете что директива include должна начинаться как в С++ с '#', так что сделайте так что бы у вас получилось так

```
include "/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc"
```

Возможно поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, да, если раскомментировать в файле "nanorc" (по месту жительства: /etc/nanorc) строку типа "#include "/usr/share/nano/pov.nanorc"", то подсветка этого языка становится доступной

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за помощь, проблема ОЧЕНЬ ПРОСТО была решена - оказывается, всего лишь нужно было при создании файла (через nano) указать сразу его расширение, то есть для использовани подсветки синтаксиса в C++ нужно было указать расширения файла .cpp

Comment: Как всегда, все оказалось проще :)
Советую обратить внимание на GUIшный редактор: http://www.sublimetext.com/